# Setting password for zip file using DotNetZip

Tags: vb.net, dotnetzip

```
        Using zip As ZipFile = New ZipFile
            zip.Password = "Test"
            zip.AddFile("C:\Test.txt", "")
            zip.Comment = ("This zip file was created at " & DateTime.Now.ToString("G"))
            zip.Save(path)
        End Using
```

Hey everyone! I am working with DotNetZip and I need some help. My password does not get set. For some reason it doesn't notice that I have put a password on the files. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue. Turns out if the file/filesize is empty or 0kb it will act as though since there is nothing there why password protect it.